# How do I make my search box work for only my website?

Tags: html, css, search

I am making a website for my high school robotics team and wanted to add a search box to the navbar, but I do not know how to get it to work without downloading one from a website or google. However, I already have my box made and would just like to know how to get it running to search for things on my site. Here is my html and for it. It is click-to-expand and then search.

```css
input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #6dcff6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
}


/* placeholder */

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}


/* demo B */

#demo-b input[type=search] {
  width: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#demo-b input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#demo-b input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}

#demo-b input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#demo-b input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo-b">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have access to a server-side scripting language (e.g. PHP, C#, ASP, Ruby, etc.)? Otherwise it might be challenging to handle the search

Comment: you can use google's custom search to achieve this

Comment: @SamOnela I could use php, however I am not fluent in the language and could not find anything to assist me